# Publish unions of all previous subscriptions

Tags: meteor, meteor-publications, meteor-collections

I have a large searchable dataset. Sending the entire dataset before rendering the page is unacceptably slow, so we're currently just sending over the portion that encompasses the search, thusly

```
if ( Meteor.isClient ) {
  Meteor.subscribe('events', Session.get('searchQuery'));
}

if ( Meteor.isServer ) {
  Meteor.publish('events', function(searchQuery) {
    return Events.find(searchQuery);
  }
}
```

Say I have 10,000 events in January and 5,000 events in February.

```
//forgive the psuedo code
Session.set('searchQuery', { startDate:  "2015-01-01", endDate: "2015-02-28"});
//wait a bit...
Event.find().count() // => 15,000, as expected.

//now I want to look at just February events
Session.set('searchQuery', { startDate:  "2015-02-01", endDate: "2015-02-28"});
Event.find().count() // => 5,000, I've lost the January events.

// now I want to look at *just* the January events
// (I previously fetched these but subsequently lost them)
Session.set('searchQuery', { startDate:  "2015-01-01", endDate: "2015-01-31"});
Event.find().count() // => 10,000, it takes a while to get all 10,000 records again.
```

What I'd like is to only ever have to publish these records once, and the resultant client side collection being the union of all previous results.

```
Session.set('searchQuery', { startDate:  "2015-01-01", endDate: "2015-02-28"});
//wait a bit...
Event.find().count() // => 15,000, as expected.

//now I want to look at just February events
Session.set('searchQuery', { startDate:  "2015-02-01", endDate: "2015-02-28"});
Event.find().count() // => 15,000, I've retained the January events.
Event.find({ startDate:  "2015-02-01", endDate: "2015-02-28"}).count() // => 5,000

// now I want to look at *just* the January events
// (I previously fetched these but subsequently lost them)
Session.set('searchQuery', { startDate:  "2015-01-01", endDate: "2015-02-31"});
Event.find().count() // => 15,000, still have all the records
Event.find({ startDate:  "2015-01-01", endDate: "2015-01-31"}).count() // => 10,000, instantly without needing the records to be republished
```

I don't think pub/sub works like this out of the box, but is there some way I can approximate this behavior?

Comment: I'm assuming that you're not actually displaying all 10,000 records at once. Wouldn't it be faster to just return the data that's being displayed on the screen and have a separate subscription or Meteor.method to return the full count (just the number)? It seems rather inefficient to load all of the data on the client side if you just need it to return the number or records.

Comment: I don't need to return just the number of records, we can drill down into each event for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you do need data other than just the count, why not cache the data from the query on the client? You can create a client side local collection: `EventCache = new Mongo.Collection(null)` and store the results of your `Event.find()` queries in the cache. Before you make any more calls to `Event.find()` you can first attempt to run the query on `EventCache`.

Comment: But then adding overlapping subsets requires additional logic.  In my example, what if I wanted to drill down to the first week of February which includes some days in both January and February.